# Courier-imap with sendmail setup: why is my IMAP inbox empty?

Tags: sendmail, imap, courier

I've successfully installed sendmail, but when I connect to the Courier IMAP server via Outlook, the Inbox is listed as empty. When I check the inbox with Alpine locally on the server, it has content though. Why? I do see files with content in /var/mail . Is that not where Courier-imap checks for mail?

The setup is pretty clean - I run Ubuntu 12.04 on AWS, have installed sendmail and courier-imap. sendmail was configured with `sendmailconfigure` and it works well to both send and receive mail. The problem is with courier.

Answer (score 0):

Courier prefers qmail-style [Maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir)s<sup>1</sup>, sendmail doesn't get involved much in the local delivery, it hands it over to an external program as defined by the `local` mailer, e.g.:

```
$ grep ^Mlocal /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
Mlocal,         P=/usr/bin/procmail, F=lsDFMAw5:/|@qSPfhn9, S=EnvFromL/HdrFromL, R=EnvToL/HdrToL,
```

The default LDA (*local delivery agent*) for this system is `procmail`, so:

```
$ procmail -v
[...]
Default rcfile:         $HOME/.procmailrc
    It may be writable by your primary group
Your system mailbox:    /var/mail/root
```

Courier will fallback to mbox support if you point it at an `mbox` file, `procmail` will default to mbox files, but should support maildirs, but (AFAIK) won't honour maildir++ quota.

Alpine is probably using the default `$MAIL` mbox file in `/var/mail`, or similar, i.e. where sendmail is delivering to (via procmail), but not where Courier is looking.

To solve your problem:

- identify your local mailer
- if it's not Courier's `maildrop`, throw it away and use `maildrop`
- make sure your `maildrop` is delivering to the same place Courier IMAP is looking (this depends on your userdb or LDAP or SQL configuration)

To configure sendmail to use maildrop, place this (probably) at the end of your `sendmail.mc` and rebuild `sendmail.cf`:

```
FEATURE(`local_procmail', `/usr/local/bin/maildrop', `maildrop -d $u')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> more accurately Maildir++ style, an extended Maildir format